# comparable varchar "arrays" in seperate fields but on same row

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, database-normalization, denormalization

I have a table that looks like this:

```
memberno(int)|member_mouth (varchar)|Inspected_Date (varchar)
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
12           |'1;2;3;4;5;6;7'       |'12-01-01;12-02-02;12-03-03' [7 members]
```

So by looking at how this table has been structured (poorly yes)

The values in the `member_mouth` field is a string that is delimited by a ";" 
The values in the `Inspected_Date` field is a string that is delimited by a ";"

So - for each delimited value in `member_mouth` there is an equal `inspected_date` value delimited inside the string

This table has about 4Mil records, we have an application written in C# that normalizes the data and stores it in a separate table. The problem now is because of the size of the table it takes a long time for this to process. (the example above is nothing compared to the actual table, it's much larger and has a couple of those string "array" fields)

My question is this: What would be the best and fastest way to normilize this data in MSSQL proc? let MSSQL do the work and not a C# app?

Comment: I will try an SSIS ETL package and maybe use C# code (already done) in CLR

Comment: Since you have a normalized data model, get rid of all references to the old table.  Then drop it.

Comment: Hi Guys - Sorry it's already 10pm here in South Africa :) @Horaciux -  I'll give that a try and monitor performance thanks.

Comment: @Dan Bracuk - I wish I could but it's data we get from a 3rd party vendor, I'm in the BI team, unfortunately I don't create it, I just have to work with what they give :(

Comment: @RynoCoetzee - With 4M records, you are likely to find the stored proc is better than the external application.  You'll spend a lot of time writing C# buffer management code that MSSQL probably already does better.  In terms of the problem: is there any kind of limit to the number of entries in those renormalized fields?  Also, are the 'mouth' variables all integers the way the 'date' variables are all dates?  Do you want these values turned into actual number and date values, or left as varchar?

Comment: Hi @Andrew Wolfe, Thanks for the comment - Yes if the values can be returned as their respective data types that would be great but Jithin Shaji has given me an answer I can work with. Thanks for all the interest though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way will be SQL itself. The way followed in the below code is something which worked for me well with 2-3 lakhs of data.

I am not sure about the below code when it comes to 4 Million, but may help.

```
Declare @table table
(memberno int, member_mouth varchar(100),Inspected_Date varchar(400))

Insert into @table Values 
(12,'1;2;3;4;5;6;7','12-01-01;12-02-02;12-03-03;12-04-04;12-05-05;12-07-07;12-08-08'),
(14,'1','12-01-01'),
(19,'1;5;8;9;10;11;19','12-01-01;12-02-02;12-03-03;12-04-04;12-07-07;12-10-10;12-12-12')

Declare @tableDest table
(memberno int, member_mouth varchar(100),Inspected_Date varchar(400))
```

The table will be like.

```
Select * from @table
```

[image]

See the code from here.

```
------------------------------------------
Declare @max_len int,
        @count int = 1

Set @max_len =  (Select max(Len(member_mouth) - len(Replace(member_mouth,';','')) + 1)
                From    @table)

While @count <= @max_len
begin
    Insert  into @tableDest
    Select  memberno,
            SUBSTRING(member_mouth,1,charindex(';',member_mouth)-1),
            SUBSTRING(Inspected_Date,1,charindex(';',Inspected_Date)-1)
    from    @table
    Where   charindex(';',member_mouth) > 0
    union   
    Select  memberno,
            member_mouth,
            Inspected_Date
    from    @table
    Where   charindex(';',member_mouth) = 0

    Delete from @table
    Where   charindex(';',member_mouth) = 0

    Update  @table
    Set     member_mouth =  SUBSTRING(member_mouth,charindex(';',member_mouth)+1,len(member_mouth)),
            Inspected_Date = SUBSTRING(Inspected_Date,charindex(';',Inspected_Date)+1,len(Inspected_Date))
    Where   charindex(';',member_mouth) > 0

    Set     @count = @count + 1
End
------------------------------------------
Select  * 
from    @tableDest
Order   By memberno
------------------------------------------
```

**Result.**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can take a reference here.

[Splitting delimited values in a SQL column into multiple rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11018076/splitting-delimited-values-in-a-sql-column-into-multiple-rows)

Comment: Thank you, I'll try said code during the course of the day and reply accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Do it on SQl server side, if possible a SSIS package would be great.