# Return multiple records from one record in SQL Server?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a table with 2 columns:

- Id (identity)
- Details (varchar(max))

The data in the details column have a special format in the form of:

```
item|value1|value2\r\nitem|value1|value2\r\n etc...
```

Is it possible to build a sql statement that parses the details column and returns the detail 'records' as rows each having 3 columns (item, value1, value2)?

Would this solution perform better than writing a method in C#?

This kind of question was already asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11018076/splitting-delimited-values-in-a-sql-column-into-multiple-rows), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/314824/t-sql-opposite-to-string-concatenation-how-to-split-string-into-multiple-reco?lq=1) or even [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647/how-do-i-split-a-string-so-i-can-access-item-x). However the answers supplied there only handle one kind of delimiter. My data have 2 delimiters:

1. | (pipe) as column delimiter
2. \r\n as row delimiter

Comment: Why do you store multiple records in one column? Create another table that references the main table via foreign-key.

Comment: You can Create Function in Database instead of c# method

Comment: @TimSchmelter it's a legacy database and this table has millions of rows.

Comment: This should do it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11018076/splitting-delimited-values-in-a-sql-column-into-multiple-rows

Comment: Please learn how to use the search function.