# How to retrieve a value from sql server (While inserting a data use a Stuff function)

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server

I am using `stuff function` to insert a value which is separated by comma.

Now I want to retrieve those value and each value which is separated by comma is unique and store these value in another variable and use them 
e.g product_id(10,5,9).

This is one row data now I want to read and store there id in separate variable

Comment: Some sample data would go a long way in solving your problem

Comment: Here the Sample Data for eg. (column name data) product_id(10,5,9) Now I want to read each Id seprately

Comment: Please edit your question to include the data, with proper formatting, so we can understand better.

Answer (score 0):

Check this example. may be work for you. But this is for a single record, if you wish, then you need again a extra loop above this loop.

```
declare @S varchar(30)
set @S = '10,5,9'

declare @tempVariableTostoreID int 
while len(@S) > 0
begin      
  --here you can store it on another variable
  select @tempVariableTostoreID = LOWER( left(@S, charindex(',', @S+',')-1) )  
  select @tempVariableTostoreID
  set @S = stuff(@S, 1, charindex(',', @S+','), '')
end
```

May I ask a question, why you split and need to store in again variable. What is your goal?

**Updated**

As per you comment check this. First you create a table-valued function from any of this link and then use this sqlscript.

Create Split function:

http://ole.michelsen.dk/blog/split-string-to-table-using-transact-sql.html
http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=50648

[Splitting delimited values in a SQL column into multiple rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11018076/splitting-delimited-values-in-a-sql-column-into-multiple-rows)

[How to split a single column values to multiple column values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5123585/how-to-split-a-single-column-values-to-multiple-column-values)

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/21078/t-sql-table-valued-function-to-split-a-column-on-commas

```
create table product (productid int, productname ntext)
create table orderhistory (orderID int, username varchar(100), productid varchar(100) )

insert into product values(1, 'P1')
insert into product values(2, 'P2')
insert into product values(3, 'P3')
insert into product values(4, 'P4')
insert into product values(5, 'P5')


select orderid, username , p.productname from
(
    select oh.orderid, oh.username ,item from orderhistory oh 
    cross apply dbo.Split(oh.productid , ',') 
)
a join product p on p.productid = a.item
```

Comment: For My college project I'm building e commerce site and this is order table column which hold the product id of various product now If I want to show the product History for eg. the product purchase by the user I need To separate these value and compare them then show the order History