# Stripping out dates, of several formats, from strings

Tags: sql-server, string, t-sql, sql-server-2014

I have a column of strings, called "MyStrings" like the following:

```
...
Foo bar Jul15 blah blah.xlsx
Choo bar Jul-15 blah far.xlsx
Star bar 10-Jul-15 blah far.xlsx
Car Star bar 10.Jul.2015 blah far.xlsx
...
...
```

I'd like to do string manipulation so all dates, whatever format, are not included in the results.

So the following query:

```
SELECT  results = <manipulated "MyStrings">
FROM    aTable
```

Should have these results:

```
...
Foo bar  blah blah.xlsx
Choo bar  blah far.xlsx
Star bar  blah far.xlsx
Car Star bar  blah far.xlsx
...
...
```

Is there a quick way of doing this or do I need to consider each format individually?

Comment: In your example the month is always 3 characters, so maybe you could use that. Search for 'words' (units delimited by spaces), containing 3 letters and (some?) digits.

Comment: don't think you're gonna find a simple solution to this with multiple formats.

Comment: @Tanner ye of little faith...I'm still hopeful

Comment: Good luck. This is going to require human intervention to pull this off. There just way too many possibilities when the format is all over the place like that.

Comment: @SeanLange so many pessimists ....someone out there might have bumped into this before

Comment: LOL the difference between a pessimist and an optimist? Experience. :) Just from the very controlled values you posted this is challenging. From what is likely all kinds of formats this is just not feasible to do accurately. July, Jul, Jun, June, Jan, January etc...and that doesn't even take into account fat fingering.

Comment: @SeanLange fat fingering... i'm gonna steal that one!

Comment: @SeanLange there is something like mysql [STR_TO_DATE()](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-str_to_date/) on MSSQL?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza there is nothing like that function in sql server that I know of. That looks pretty robust. There is DateFromParts https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213228.aspx but it can't handle all the extra characters that MySql function can.

Comment: @SeanLange Ok guys check my version.  I think is a good start. Feel free to offer hint to improve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a [**Split function**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11018076/splitting-delimited-values-in-a-sql-column-into-multiple-rows)

If you split first by `<space>` is easy create regular expresion for

```
monDD
mon-DD
DD-mon-YY
DD-mon-YYYY
```

**[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f18dc/6)**

```
WITH splitCTE AS (
  SELECT s.[id], f.Number, f.Item
  FROM dbo.SourceData AS s
  CROSS APPLY dbo.SplitStrings(s.[test], ' ') as f
)
  SELECT *,
         CASE
             WHEN item Like 'Jul[0-9][0-9]' THEN 'mmmdd'
             WHEN item Like 'Jul-[0-9][0-9]' THEN 'mmm-dd'
             WHEN item Like '[0-9][0-9]-Jul-[0-9][0-9]' THEN 'dd-mmm-yy'
             WHEN item Like '[0-9][0-9].Jul.[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]' THEN 'dd.mmm.yyyy'
             ELSE ''
         END matchType         
  FROM splitCTE
```

**OUTPUT**

- Need a join with list of 3 char months to replace the wired `Jul`.
- Easy expand to also include a version with full month name.
- Will match `Jul77` as `mmmdd` but is a start.
- You can calculate a IsValidDate column in another step

  - For some of the format you can use `CONVERT` to check for a valid date
  - For other like `Jul77` you can separate first 3 char with last 2 and try to get a date.

.

```
| id | Number |        Item |   matchType |
|----|--------|-------------|-------------|
|  1 |      1 |         Foo |             |
|  1 |      2 |         bar |             |
|  1 |      3 |       Jul15 |       mmmdd |
|  1 |      4 |        blah |             |
|  1 |      5 |   blah.xlsx |             |
|  2 |      1 |        Choo |             |
|  2 |      2 |         bar |             |
|  2 |      3 |      Jul-15 |      mmm-dd |
|  2 |      4 |        blah |             |
|  2 |      5 |    far.xlsx |             |
|  3 |      1 |        Star |             |
|  3 |      2 |         bar |             |
|  3 |      3 |   10-Jul-15 |   dd-mmm-yy |
|  3 |      4 |        blah |             |
|  3 |      5 |    far.xlsx |             |
|  4 |      1 |         Car |             |
|  4 |      2 |        Star |             |
|  4 |      3 |         bar |             |
|  4 |      4 | 10.Jul.2015 | dd.mmm.yyyy |
|  4 |      5 |        blah |             |
|  4 |      6 |    far.xlsx |             |
```

Then use your favorite **[XML PATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194852/concatenate-many-rows-into-a-single-text-string)** to join back without the matching elements

Comment: there are quite a few - this is a great start