# SQL Server date range generate to multiple rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, recursive-query, unpivot, date-arithmetic

**TableName**

Sample data

```
Number Date_From   Date_To   
1      2020-09-29  2020-09-30
```

I need to return something like this:

```
Number Date_generated
1      2020-09-29
1      2020-09-30
```

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18026236/sql-server-columns-to-rows Or try searching for the words ___sql server columns to rows___

Comment: You're showing pivoting, not generating a range. What do you actually want? What if `Date_To` was `2020-10-30`? Would you expect 2 rows or 31?

Answer (score 4):

You can unpivot with a lateral join:

```
select t.number, x.date_generated
from mytable t
cross apply (values (t.date_from), (t.date_to)) as x(date_generated)
```

On the other hand, if you want to generate one row per day within the range, one option  uses a recursive query:

```
with cte as (
    select number, date_from date_generated, date_to from mytable
    union all
    select number, dateadd(day, 1, date_generated), date_to from cte where date_generated < date_to
)
select * from cte
```

If you have ranges that span over more than 100 days, then you need to add `option (maxrecursion 0)` at the very end of the query.

Answer (score 0):

Based on question already asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11018076/splitting-delimited-values-in-a-sql-column-into-multiple-rows) :
You can use this function to split your string with the desired delimiter. in your case it's '|'

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.SplitStrings
(
    @List       NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @Delimiter  NVARCHAR(255)
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
    RETURN (SELECT Number = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Number),
        Item FROM (SELECT Number, Item = LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(@List, Number, 
        CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @List + @Delimiter, Number) - Number)))
    FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY s1.[object_id])
        FROM sys.all_objects AS s1 CROSS APPLY sys.all_objects) AS n(Number)
    WHERE Number <= CONVERT(INT, LEN(@List))
        AND SUBSTRING(@Delimiter + @List, Number, 1) = @Delimiter
    ) AS y);
```

Use it like it :

```
SELECT s.[message-id], f.Item
  FROM dbo.SourceData AS s
  CROSS APPLY dbo.SplitStrings(s.[recipient-address], '|') as f;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
select number,date_from Date_generated from tbl
union all
select number,date_to Date_generated from tbl
```